# Angular 6 testing: How to provide services without their nested dependencies?

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine, karma-runner, injectable

I have a `ComponentA` that uses an `ServiceA`. I'm writing a test for `ComponentA`, adding `ServiceA` into testbed providers. I run the test and get following error:

```
StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[ServiceA -> ServiceB]
NullInjectorError: No provider for ServiceB!
```

I add `ServiceB` to providers. I run the test again and now I get:

```
StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[ServiceB -> ServiceC]
NullInjectorError: No provider for ServiceC!
```

My project has many nested dependencies, all services have `@Injectable` decorator. How can I avoid providing long list of nested services?

Comment: Posible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40319045/mock-custom-service-in-angular2-during-unit-test

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mock custom service in angular2 during unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40319045/mock-custom-service-in-angular2-during-unit-test)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your .spec.ts file:

```
 providers: [
     {provide: YourService, useClass: YourMockService},
  ]
```

YourMockService will have the same methods as YourService but will just be typically empty methods. Here's a mock service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'

@Injectable()
export class YourMockService {

  get user() {
    // this is mock data
    return {username: 'fred'}
  }

  public getFromLocalStorage(k: string) {
    return []
  }
}
```

YourService will have these same methods and getters but will, for example, perform HTTP requests, etc to get the username.

Comment: If DI service in turn depends on other services?  Any way to 'not require' to create spies/stubs for those?  something like 'NO_ERROR_SCHEMA' for components?